# Facebook Page Tab iFrame App - invite friend requests

Tags: php, facebook, iframe

I have an FB application which is loading as Page Tab through iFrame. Considering that FBML is being removed completely as of 1st June 2012, is there a way to create invite friend request on the page tab app? I've researched the request dialog docs but that is only available to canvas apps(?)

Answer (score 1):

The requests dialog only works on canvas app, i lost 4 hours to discover that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request dialog also on tab application

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: I tried. Popup dialog shows up, I can select friends and press send but request is never delivered. 
I've user FB Send instead as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The request dialog works for me on my page tab app. You can see the implementation details in
[my post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11052691/multi-friend-selector-and-authentication-dialog-in-pagetab-app).

The only problem I had was that I didn't want it as a popup but on the page, which I am still trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: Isn't there a way to redirect back ?